# Macbook Air connects to 2.4ghz but shows exclamation point for 5ghz

Tags: macos, network, wifi, internet

I just recently moved and set up my same router with a new name. When I connect to the 2.4ghz wifi network the internet runs okay, but when I try to connect to 5ghz it shows an exclamation point over the wifi logo and I have no internet. What steps should I take to try to fix this? Our 2.4ghz network is SO slow.

System info:
MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76)

Troubleshooting steps:

- My Macbook Pro and all other devices connect to 5ghz just fine.
- I tried a different router and had the exact same issue.
- Ran `sudo ifconfig en1 down` and `sudo ifconfig en1 up` in Terminal
- Changed my MAC address
- Deleted `NetworkInterfaces.plist` and `preferences.plist` and rebooted my computer.

Help! And thank you.